# cygwin.s file missing C++ Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The debugger has been working fine until now. This was probably the first time I debugged a program with array of objects, the program "runs" but has all sorts of garbage values and data are misplaced. While debugging the program gives out the cygwin.s file missing in MIGW path and prompts me to create it.

My program is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    char name[100];
    int roll;
    int marks;

    public:

    void getdata()
    {
        cout<<"Enter students name, roll no and marks: "<<endl;
        cin>>name>>roll>>marks;
    }

    void showdata()
    {
        cout<<name<<endl<<roll<<endl<<marks<<endl;
    }

friend void sort_marks(student s[10], int n);
};

void sort_marks(student obs[10], int n)
{
    student temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (obs[i].marks > obs[j].marks)
            {
                temp = obs[i];
                obs[i] = obs[j];
                obs[j] = temp;
            } 
        }  
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of students: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    student obs[n]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//Students details
    {
        student obs[i];
        obs[i].getdata();
    }   

    sort_marks(obs, n);
    cout<<"The highest marks is attained by: "<<endl;
    obs[n].showdata();
    cout<<"The third highest mark is attained by: "<<endl;
    obs[n-2].showdata();
}
```

While using the debugger with breakpoints at for loop in main() function, i get the error when the loop runs the second time. The program itself might be a little buggy because i havent been able to fix it without locating the problem as the debugger is broken.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095493/debugger-in-cb-cant-open-cygwin-s

Comment: `student obs[n];` VLAs in C++? I don't think so. In any case, even if there were, the declaration inside the loop would shadow the actual array outside the loop.

Comment: @paxdiablo could you please elaborate. and how could i get around this?

Comment: At it's simplest, `student *obs = new student[n];`. Better would be using a `std::vector`.

Comment: the issue still persists. thank tho

Comment: I got it, it was because Im declaring student objects twice.